Regular octagon inscribed in an ellipse
Problem
A regular octagon inscribed in an ellipse. The foci of the ellipse $F_1$ and $F_2$ are on the midpoint of a side of a regular octagon.



Proof the eccentricity of the ellipse is $e=\frac{\sqrt{14+8\sqrt{2}-2\sqrt{69+48\sqrt{2}}}}{2}$
My attempt:
Let point A be the vertice of regular octagon which is on the ellipse, $s$ be the side length of the regular octagon.



Using the definition:
$AF_1+AF_2=2a$
Also $e=\frac{a}{c}$
I can express $AF_1$ and focal length $2c$ in term of $s$ easily by using trigonometry.
I am having difficulties in expressing $AF_2$ in term of $s$.
How can I solve this question?

Please define your variables. Can you clarify what is $c$ and $s$? In particular, the equation $ e = a/c$ to be seems suspect. I was expecting $ e = \sqrt{a^2-b^2}/a$.

(±c,0) is foci, s is the side length of regular octagon

If $H$ is the projection of $A$ on $F_1F_2$, then it's easy to compute $AH$, $F_1H$ and $F_2H$. Moreover, $e=c/a$, not $a/c$.
